# Scalefactor zoom amount on WebView double tap

Tags: android, webview, android-canvas, gesture

I'm implementing a canvas on a WebView and I need to have the canvas scale according to the zoom level of the WebView. Combining `canvas.scale()` with a `SimpleOnScaleListener` does the trick. For the double tap, I'm using a `GestureDetector` which detects when there's a double tap and sets the scale factor accordingly. I'm merely guessing how much it scales when there is a double tap: Setting the scale factor to `2.2f` works on a 7in tablet but it scales too much for a 10in.

Is there anyway to programmatically figure out how much the WebView has zoomed in on double tap? I basically need the canvas to synchronize zooming with the WebView.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    invalidate();
}

public class ScaleGestureListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {                
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        if(Deal.on == false) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 30.0f));
            System.out.println("mScaleFactor: " + mScaleFactor);
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

public class DoubleTapListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
       if (Deal.on == false) {
           if (mScaleFactor > 1.0f) {
               mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
           }else {
               mScaleFactor = 2.2f;
           }
       }
       return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch zoom change by extending `WebViewClient`

```
public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
            super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
            currentScale = newScale;
        }
    });
}
```